# Плавающий блок с position:fixed

Tags: jquery, javascript

На пальцах объяснить трудно, вот пикча, того что я хочу сделать:

[image]

- Зеленые блоки это блоки с
     position:fixed;
- Красные полоски - границы экрана;
- Желтые блоки - это области в которых
     из которых не могут выйти зеленые
     блоки. Если листать выше или ниже, то
     зеленые блоки остаются на крайней
     границе желтых;

Каким способом лучше сделать?

Comment: Высота голубого блока известна?

Comment: известна :) $('.blue').outerHeight()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/49T4d/3/)**

**html**

```
<div id="railway_lines">
    <div class="rails">
        <div class="truck"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rails">
        <div class="truck"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div#railway_lines {
    background-color: #55c1ff;
    height: 1200px;
    position: relative;
}
div.rails, div.truck {
    width: 80px;
}
div.rails {
    background-color: #ffee33;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
div.rails:first-child {
    left: 0;
}
div.rails:not(:first-child) {
    right: 0;
}
div.truck {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    position: fixed;
    height: 120px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

**javascript**

```
var truck = $(".truck"),
    rails = $(".rails"),
    css_top_onmove = $(rails[0]).css('top'),
    css_top_onhold = $(rails).height() - $(truck).height(),
    css_left = $(rails[0]).css('left'),
    css_right = $(rails[1]).css('right');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var pos_top = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (pos_top > css_top_onhold) {
        $(truck).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': css_top_onhold + 'px'
        });

        $(truck[0]).css('left', css_left);
        $(truck[1]).css('right', css_right);
    } else {
        $(truck).css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': css_top_onmove,
            'left': '',
            'right': ''
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @VenZell, А если свойств побольше будет, вы для каждого будете метод .css() писать? Может проще так?

    $(selector).css({
        property_1: value_1,
        property_2: value_2,
        /* ... */
        property_N: value_N
    });

Comment: @Deonis, вы абсолютно правы. Упустил этот момент. :)

Answer (score 1):

Скриптом определять `$(window).scrollTop()`, затем сравнивать с положением верхней ( `$('.yellow').offset().top` ) и нижней ( `$('.yellow').ofset().top+$('.yellow').outerHeight()` ) границ жёлтой области. Если положение верхней границы жёлтой области большей, чем `$(window).scrollTop()`, то давать класс, в котором описано статическое положение зелёного блока. Если же положение нижней границы меньше, чем высота зелёного блока, то зафиксировать зелёный блок в нижней части жёлтого например абсолютом. В остальных случаях просто `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

А зачем позиционирование то использовать, если гораздо проще с помощью отступов сделать??

Вот вариант плавающего блока в сайдбаре без использования position и блок не наезжает на подвал - http://makeasite.ru/blog/sticky-block-at-sidebar.html